# Selecting row with multiple parameters (ajax and PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Good Day,
I'm new to PHP/MySQL and I try to send a request from ajax and select a row in a database with multiple parameters.
Is this the good way to do that ?

> AJAX (Jquery):

```
function readLine(name, firstname) {
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "./php/readLine.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { name: name, firstname: firstname },
        success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
        }
        error: function(data) {
         console.log("An error occured!");
        }
});
}
```

> PHP:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE firstname=".intval($_POST['firstname'])." AND name=".intval($_POST['name']);
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "myDB");
if (!$con) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$to_encode = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){
  $to_encode[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($to_encode);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, but that's about the worst way to do it. You're ***wide*** open to SQL injection attacks. Research 'prepared statements' for a better approach

Comment: 'name' and 'firstname' are strings... So I guess I shouldn't use 'intval' in my PHP code... But what should I use then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, **you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead**, as currently the code is susceptible to SQL Injection attacks. I cannot emphasise this enough, an attacker would be able to wreak havoc on your database with the code you currently have.

You should use something like the following (taken from the page linked above, and [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#107568) on the same page). Note that I have removed the `intval` calls to your POSTed data, as I assume they are strings rather than integers.

```
$to_encode = array();
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "myDB");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE firstname=? AND name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['name']);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* instead of bind_result: */
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    /* now you can fetch the results into an array - NICE */
    while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        // use your $myrow array as you would with any other fetch
        $to_encode[] = $myrow;

    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

echo json_encode($to_encode);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using PDO with prepared statements, that'll make sure the user input is made safe. Like this:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=db_name;host=localhost', 'db_user', 'db_password');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE firstname=:firstname AND name=:name"; 
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $_POST['firstname'], PDO::PARAM_STRING); 
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STRING); 
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

echo json_encode($result);
```

Move the first 5 lines into an include, then you only need this code once.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name=? and firstname=?");
$stmt->bind_param($name ,$firstname);

// set parameters and execute
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($to_encode);

$stmt->fetch();

echo json_encode($to_encode);
```

Comment: You don't need `mysqli_real_escape_string` when using prepared statements, it does this for you.